# Can I Disable text notification noise Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I am in the process of developing an app that would silence texting notifications (sending the message straight to the inbox maybe)

I am using Lollipop.

Is there code out there that would make this possible?

Here is what i have got thus far.

**FIRST JAVA CLASS**

```
public class NoNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        abortBroadcast();

    }

}
```

**SECOND JAVA FILE**

```
    private static final String CHECK_OP_NO_THROW = "checkOpNoThrow";
    private static final String OP_POST_NOTIFICATION = "OP_POST_NOTIFICATION";

    public static boolean isNotificationEnabled(Context context) {

        AppOpsManager mAppOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);

        ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();

        String pkg = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

        int uid = appInfo.uid;

        Class appOpsClass = null; /* Context.APP_OPS_MANAGER */

        try {

            appOpsClass = Class.forName(AppOpsManager.class.getName());

            Method checkOpNoThrowMethod = appOpsClass.getMethod(CHECK_OP_NO_THROW, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class);

            Field opPostNotificationValue = appOpsClass.getDeclaredField(OP_POST_NOTIFICATION);
            int value = (int)opPostNotificationValue.get(Integer.class);

            return ((int)checkOpNoThrowMethod.invoke(mAppOps,value, uid, pkg) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Could I possibly be missing some permissions?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I searched through the android api refrence and could not find any way to do this. This is probally for security reasons, however i'm pretty sure it would be posible using root.

Comment: I did some research of my own and ive been seeing a lot of comments talking about using root (SIGH). Also seen stuff about using special API and doing quite a bit of manifest work.

Comment: With an unrooted phone I don't think this is possible at the app level.